# Change display resolution from command line / batch file

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors, batch-file, resolution

I know similar questions have been asked before, but i am looking to change the display resolution **and** scanline order (Progressive / Interlaced) on multiple monitors using the command line.
The solution cannot be device specific as it is to be used across multiple PCs.

I have looked at using [Display Changer II from 12Noon](http://12noon.com/?page_id=641), [ChangeScreenResolution.exe](http://tools.taubenkorb.at/change-screen-resolution/), NirSoft's NirCmd and MultiMonitorTool , as well as some others.. Starting to loose track now! 
(using Windows 7 professional on 64 bit PCs)

So far the only one which is able to specify using Interlaced (upper field first) is Display Changer II, and this works, but the problem is that it uses an XML file where it specifics device specific information, meaning the the XML cannot simply by copied onto another PC to use.

Something like ChangeScreenResolution.exe would be perfect if it could specify this, as it could be used on multiple computers to set display 1 to the correct settings:

```
ChangeScreenResolution.exe /d=1 /w=1920 /h=1080 /b=32 /f=50 /scan=interlaced_upper
```

Does anyone know of a solution for this or an alternative bit of software.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: As it is device specific whenever a display would support interlacing it's probably going to be hard to find a universal solution.